# Node.js convert hexadecimal number to byteArray

Tags: node.js, buffer

I want to send a raw buffer using bluetooth connection. The content is a hex number. Currently I split the number manually to an byte array. Is there any function that can help me convert the number to byte array?

```
//var data = 0x250001000192CD0000002F6D6E742F72;
var data = new Buffer([0x25,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x92,0xCD,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2F,0x6D,0x6E,0x74,0x2F,0x72]);
serialPort.write(data);
```

Answer (score 171):

In new versions of node (6+) the `new Buffer()` interface is deprecated. Use:

```
Buffer.from("250001000192CD0000002F6D6E742F72", "hex")
```

instead.

Find more info on this using this link below
https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_string_encoding

Comment: Only use this if you don‘t care about any validity-checking on the input; `Buffer.from("abc 123 foo bar baz", "hex")` returns `<Buffer ab>`

Comment: Hey Googlers, this is the right answer! C'mon @GingerJim!

Answer (score 77):

```
new Buffer("250001000192CD0000002F6D6E742F72", "hex")
```

Comment: This usage is deprecated. See other answer for modern API.

Comment: `new Buffer()` is deprecated. new usage is `new Buffer.from()`