# Convert string containing binary hex in ASCII into Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am using node.js.

I have this string `msg_str` with the following contents `"0102ab00aabb00"`. I want to convert this string content (ASCII representing binary hex) and store it into a Buffer such that the contents of the Buffer looks like `<01 02 ab 00 aa bb 00 >`.

Some preliminary code I wrote which does not work as expected;

```
msg_str = "0102ab00aabb00";
buffer_binary = new Buffer(msg_str);
console.log(msg_str);   
console.log(buffer_binary);
```

The console output of `buffer_binary` is `30 31 30 32 61 62 30 30 61 61 62 62 30 30`. The correct output should be `01 02 ab 00 aa bb 00`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js convert hexadecimal number to byteArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880301/node-js-convert-hexadecimal-number-to-bytearray)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell the `Buffer` constructor that your string is in hex.  Fortunately, this is pretty easy :)

```
msg_str = "0102ab00aabb00";
buffer_binary = new Buffer(msg_str, "hex"); // specify hex
console.log(msg_str); // logs 0102ab00aabb00
console.log(buffer_binary); // logs <Buffer 01 02 ab 00 aa bb 00>
```

Comment: is there a way to do this in the browser?